# Lerp RenderSettings no longer works in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, skybox

I want a skybox that lerps between two skyboxes, here's my code. It simply doesn't lerp the skybox, I've tested `_timePercent` with simply `0.5f` and doesn't do anything, I've double-checked my list of skyboxes and that's fine. From what it seems, the feature has been removed. Setting the skybox directly works but that's not what I want to do. So it's not an issue with the code actually being called-to

```
RenderSettings.skybox.Lerp(skyboxes[0], skyboxes[1], _timePercent);
DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();
```

Comment: the factor would need to be a continuously increasing value .. how exactly do you call this? Are you sure it is called at all? ([mcve]) Also just to be sure: your materials should all use the same shader to match properties .. you sure your skybox has the correct shader/Material?

Comment: It's definitely being called and the lerp value is set between 0 and 1. The skyboxes I'm using are Skybox/Panoramic so are they not compatible with the Lerp feature? What other skybox materials are compatible with it?

Comment: This Lerp feature has nothing to do with skyboxes in specific .. this is [`Material.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.Lerp.html) which basically takes all the shader properties amd interpolates between the values of both given materials accordingly .. so all three materials, the one currently assigned to `RenderSettings.skybox` as well as the ones in `skyboxes` should use the same shader as base or at least compatible shader properties